# Android Developer Tools: remove bottom onscreen buttons

Tags: android, button, android-virtual-device

in AVD I created custom device with 3" screen.

When using api 17 and editing any layout xml if I switch to grafical layout there are buttons ('back', 'home' and 'options'<- not sure about last one name) on the bottom of the screen.

I can't get rid of them! Please help me out 'cause they messing my layout preview

P.S. The layout theme is no title bar and fullscreen

Comment: Use FullScreenActivity while selecting the project. It contains the default code to hide the hardware buttons until a user interacts with the screen

Comment: This is the correct (and expected) behavior. On Android 3.0 and above, these software buttons replace hardware buttons. Without them, many devices (such as the Galaxy Nexus) would no longer be able to go back, home, or to the recent apps list.

Comment: @Tanis.7x I see your point. Then how can you explain that these button only shown when I switch to my custom device screen and there are no buttons on any of generic screens?
So your comment is not an answer for my question but just a statement of well-known fact

Comment: @JibranKhan I already have a big project and not creating a new one.
On all other generic device screens there are no buttons. Only when I switch to my custom device screen. And as I said: 'The layout theme is no title bar and fullscreen'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys. It seems to be a visual bug in ADT.
The buttons disappeared when I relaunched it.